# Set a package as predefined to every file

Tags: org-mode, package

I'm trying to set the package `org-bullets` as predefined in every `*.org` file because is kind of redundant to write `M-x org-bullets` every time I work with the format. Is this  possible?

Comment: What do you mean by a package being "predefined" in a given file? Do you really mean to ask how to enable some mode in every Org file - e.g., a mode defined in some package?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I mean to set it up in _every_ file I work with in org-mode so I can avoid to type M-x org-bullets. It is not something of high importance but I think that it's something simple and should have to be an option

Comment: I just had to add (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1))) to my init file. Solved.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post the answer. You can accept your own answer. But please clarify the question, so it and the answer can help others. Thx.

Comment: The answer is just above your comment.

Comment: Comments risk being deleted at any time. An answer is the place to put an answer. And it's the place for the OP to tell others which answer helped the most. The site is about Q & A - it's about users finding useful questions and answers.

Comment: This is also OP's third new account in three days. This site is a community with established ways of asking & answering questions. It will be easier for people to help you if you take a few minutes to learn how this place works

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-bullets-mode)` to my init file. Solved.

Comment: Can you say how/why that solved the problem? That will help readers of the question and answer.

Comment: You don't need to wrap that into a lambda `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-bullets-mode)` should suffice.